# MySQL trigger with nested select

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

I am trying to create a MySQL trigger which runs after insert on table A and am concerned with multiple rows.  Basically, when I insert into table A, I want to insert a row into table B with the every row from table C and and the inserted ID from table A.  Can someone help?

This is the general idea -

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER mailings_create AFTER INSERT ON mailings FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN   
    SELECT
        customer_id,
        first_name,
        last_name,
        email
    INTO
        customer_id,
        first_name,
        last_name,
        email
    FROM
        cam_customers
    WHERE
        mail_list = 'T'
        AND email IS NOT NULL;

    foreach ($data as $row) {
        INSERT INTO
            mailings_messages
            (mailings_id, first_name, last_name, customer_id, email)
        VALUES
            (NEW.id, first_name, lsat_name, customer_id, email);
    }
...
```

Thanks!

Evan

Answer (score 1):

How about -

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER mailings_create AFTER INSERT ON mailings
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

        INSERT INTO mailings_messages
            (mailings_id, first_name, last_name, customer_id, email)
        SELECT NEW.id, first_name, last_name, customer_id, email
        FROM cam_customers
        WHERE mail_list = 'T'
        AND email IS NOT NULL;

        SELECT @row_count := ROW_COUNT();
        -- INSERT or UPDATE using @row_count here

    END;
|

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: That is AWESOME - one more thing - how would I add something at the end to update 'messages' in 'mailings' with the number of rows that was inserted?

Comment: You can use `SELECT ROW_COUNT();` to retrieve the number of rows inserted by the previous query. I will update my answer.